# How do I show the entire datatable in an R Shiny application?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe of 14 rows but for some reason it's only showing 10 out of those 13. I want to be able to see the entire dataframe but I don't know how to do that. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

And in this picture you can see the rest (unordered)

[image]

Comment: `?DT::datatable` it's in the docs `options = list(pageLength = 15)` https://datatables.net/reference/option/pageLength

Comment: I think it's not within `?DT::datatable` (at least not on my machine with DT-0.15), just on the web pages. Your second link has it, but isn't that the underlying JS library, not the R package? (See https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html)

Comment: rawr you solved the issue. If you want to post it as an answer I will check it and vote up for you.

Comment: @r2evans yes `?DT::datatable` links to the js library under the `options` argument. from the way it is phrased, it sounds like you can use any of those options from the js site, not just the few listed on the rstudio page

Answer (score 0):

As Rawr stated in the comments, all I needed to do was put `pageLength = 15` in the options.